# How to get more data from Get-ADuser with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=CompanySite,DC=example,DC=domain,DC=com" -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} -Properties "SamAccountName","msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", "Department", "Title", "Manager" | 
  Select-Object -Property "SamAccountName", @{Name="Password Expiry Date"; Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}; @{Label="Manager";Expression={(Get-aduser -filter {sAMAccountName -eq $_.Manager}.sAMAaccountName)}};# |
     Export-Csv "C:\Update\PasswordExpired.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I am trying to get an CSV that contains the employees whose password is expiring and get their managers name, the employees job title, the employees name and the date the password will expire.

However when I run this, I am getting the employees name and date the password is expiring. No other fields. I dont understand where I went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there were a few errors causing issues:

1. You had a semi-colon (;) after the Password Expiry Date property in the Select-object portion.  This caused the code to terminate at that point.  It should be a comma.
2. For the Manager property, your expression is incorrect.  You have your end parentheses after SamAccountName.  It should be before the period.  Additionally you are trying to match the DN with the SamAccountName data so it will return nothing.  Just do a Get-ADUser and set the identity as the $_.Manager output.  From there you can use the parentheses to output whatever metadata you want from the full ADUser Object for the manager.  You can swap out SamAccountName to DisplayName or something else.

   ```
   Your code:    (Get-ADUser -filter {SamAccountName-eq $_.Manager}.SamAccountName)
   Correct code: (Get-ADUser $_.Manager).SamAccountName
   ```
3. Title and Name are not included because you aren't calling them in the Select-object code.  The "-Properties" section of Get-ADUser only adds the attribute to the list of retrieved attributes.  What you set in Select is what is output to the screen or file.
4. You had a comment (#) tag before the Export-CSV section so that wasn't running either.

Here's the code.  I don't have the manager attribute in my AD so I wasn't able to validate that section, but the rest ran correctly.  I've also made it a bit more transportable.  The SearchBase is now specified in a variable, as is the export location for the file.  Additionally, you don't need to specify SamAccountName in the -Properties section as this is a default attribute for Get-ADUser.

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $SearchPath = "OU=CompanySite,DC=example,DC=domain,DC=com"
    $ExportPath = 'C:\Update\PasswordExpired.csv'

    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchPath -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed", "Department", "Title", "Manager" 
    $Users | Select-Object -Property Name,"SamAccountName",Title,@{Name="Password Expiry Date"; Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}},@{Label="Manager";Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).sAMaccountName}} | Export-Csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: We have managers for the users in AD but the field doesn't populate o Export

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code.  Without having the manager data I didn't realize what was wrong.  Here's what you had versus the correction.

        Your code:    (Get-ADUser -filter {SamAccountName-eq $_.Manager}.SamaAccountName)  #NOTE you have SamAccountName misspelled
        Correct code: (Get-ADUser $_.Manager).sAMaccountName

The manager code provides the DN of the manager.  You can do a get-aduser with the $_.Manager value and then you get the full AD User Object and then you can choose to get the SamAccountName or DisplayName or whatever you want.